# Question about a proof for the theorem: If $ f $ is holomorphic and assumes its modulus at $z_0$, then $ f'\left(z_{0}\right)\neq0 $

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, analytic-functions

Im reading a proof of G.Polya and G.Szego in my complex analysis book to the following theorem:

> Suppose f is nonconstant and analytic on the closed disc D and assumes its maximum modulus at the boundary point $z_0$. Then $ f'\left(z_{0}\right)\neq0 $

I wanted to ask about a little detail in the beggining of the proof.

The proof starts as the following:

Assume that $ f'(z_0) =0 $. For any complex number $\xi $ of sufficiently small modulus we have

$ f\left(z_{0}+\xi\right)=f\left(z_{0}\right)+\frac{f^{(k)}\left(z_{0}\right)}{k!}\xi^{k}+... $

Where $k $ is the least integer with $ f^{(k)}\left(z_{0}\right)\neq0 $ and the omitted terms are all of higher order in $ \xi $ than $ \xi ^k $.

Now, what I dont get is why we can write $ f $ as a power series with center at $ z_0 $ if $ z_0 $ is on the boundary of the region where $ f $ is holomorphic? How can we tell that the convergence radius of this series is not $0$ ?

Comment: How does that book define holomorphic function for functions whose domain is a non open set $S$. My guess is that it is defined as the restriction to $S$ of a holomorhpic function defined on an open set $A\supset S$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The book  author is Joseph Bak Donal J.Newman "Complex Analysis" and it actually was not defined before, Im pretty sure because I read continuously every single line and summarize it myself

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Yes, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the statement is:

**Theorem:** Suppose $f$ is nonconstant and analytic on the closed disc $D$, and assumes its maximum modulus at the boundary point $z_0$. Then $f′(z_0)\ne0$.

And the author defines analytic function as follows:

**Definition:** $f$ is analytic on a set $S$ if $f$ is differentiable at all points of some open set containing $S$.

So, if $f$ is analytic on the closed disk $D$, then it is the restriction to $D$ of an analytic function deefined on an open set $A\supset D$. And $z_0\in A$. Therefore, it as a Taylor series with non-zero radius of convergence centered at $z_0$.